# How to dynamically colour svg images in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to get a specific part of an svg image (created in inkscape if it matters) to change colour on some event. I'm pretty sure that I can use css to do this, but I cannot figure out how to select the id from the specific svg file.
If the object in the svg has id='ToChange' and the html tag has id='svgToChange', I'd think the css would be

```
#svgToChange #ToChange :hover {...}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Would javascript be better for this?

Comment: It's not really a duplicate as he wants to do this with css not javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#svgToChange:Hover #ToChange{fill: #whatever}
```

Edit from question asker:

I figured out how to do it, the problem was because I had the svg in an img tag instead of an object tag.

Comment: quite right Daniel. I missed the # from #svgToChange thanks for that catch.

Comment: This isn't working for me for some reason? The svg's object is defined in a separate file, and is brought in using an html img tag; the object is 

     <rect
       ry="1.9039629"
       y="735.79297"
       x="124.96612"
       height="13.565736"
       width="101.48625"
       id="ToChange"
       style="fill:#4d4d4d"
       inkscape:label="#rect4527" />

Comment: can you post up a pen?

Comment: Pen? What would that be? Sorry, new to all this.

Comment: It's a way of playing with code and sharing with the community: http://codepen.io/